# apache config redirect working, but it causes another vhost non-SSL redirect to fail

Tags: apache, redirect, virtualhost

*Background and task info:* 
An outside organization, that owns an old .edu domain, provides a DNS redirect pointing from their .edu to our main homepage, www.some.foo.gov--it works. My task is to redirect any of these incoming requests to specific page on our main site--within the Apache configuration file. I have unsuccessfully tried setting up the undesired Virtual Host in order to put the redirect in place. The redirect works nicely, but nullifies a non-ssl redirect within the context of another vhost.

Apache config files code:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  www.edusite.edu
    Redirect permanent / https://www.some.foo.gov/visitnewedusite.html
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.some.foo.gov
    ServerAlias www
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/mainweb/html"

    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) https://www.some.foo.gov%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301] [L]

</VirtualHost>
```

Now any request to http://www.some.foo.gov goes to https://www.some.foo.gov/visitnewedusite.html instead of https://www.some.foo.gov .

If adding loop protection is a viable solution, which virtual host block should contain the code, www.edusite.edu or www.some.foo.gov?

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Comment: Config looks ok to me – stupid question, are you maybe lacking a [`NameVirtualHost`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost) directive so everything's falling through to the first definition?

Comment: Hmmm, good catch. I'll give this a try and get back.

Comment: Thank you, Ulrich. The NameVirtualHost directive solved the problem.